# Calling methods in Froala wysiwyg editor for React

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, froala

I'm using a rich text editor called Froala, in its React version. The docs are intended for the JQuery one. From the little that is written about React, i found these instructions:

> Events and Methods
>   Events can be passed in with the options, with a key events and object where the key is the event name and the value is the callback function.

```
options: {
 placeholder: "Edit Me",
 events : {
   'froalaEditor.focus' : function(e, editor) {
     console.log(editor.selection.get());
   }
 }
}
```

> Using the editor instance from the arguments of the callback you can call editor methods as described in the method docs. Froala events are described in the events docs.

I understand how i can use events, but not calling methods. Does it mean that i can access the editor instance, only from an event? Can someone clarify this? For instance, i would like to use the html.insert() method, as described here:

```
$('.selector').froalaEditor('html.insert', 'foo bar', true);
```

How would that be used with the Froala React component?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is interested, i implemented an easy workaround:

I use the "initialized" event, just to get the Froala instance, and place a reference to it in my class::

```
'froalaEditor.initialized' : (e, editor)=> {
    this.froalaInstance = editor;

  }
```

Now i can access the Froala instance...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in how to achieve this take a look at

https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/react/

It's pretty straight forward to define methods in the config object.